# Have to restart docker every time i make changes in python file in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-3.8

I am running into a weird situation. Our python tests are run in docker. I setup all services with command `docker-compose up -d --build`. It takes it time build it and works fine. Then i log into my docker container as `docker exec -it <name> /bin/bash` and run my test-cases. All work fine until i have to modify my python file in there.

Once i do so, my `py.test <path to file>` hangs and never runs. I do exit from docker container and run `docker-compose up -d --build` and i get this error

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/mdillon/postgis:10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            10.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/mdillon/postgis:10:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/mdillon/postgis/manifests/10": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on 192.xxx.xx.x:xx: read udp 192.xxx.xx.x:xxxxx->192.xxx.xx.x:xx: i/o timeout
ERROR: Service 'pgdb' failed to build : Build failed
```

Then i restart my docker using docker dashboard or service. it takes few seconds, it comes up and i use `docker-compose` again and everything works perfectly fine.

Another note, normally i am connected to office VPN but being connected to vpn or not doesn't make any difference.

Can someone help me understanding whats going on.

**Update**: Just noticed, editing a file is not required. If i left docker running for a while and then run `py.test` in container, they hang ... and the only fix then is to exist, restart docker, docker-compose and then run tests in container.

**Update 2**:
I tried stopping all containers and re-running them. This doesn't solve the problem. However, if i restart docker app by itself and do restart on all containers, it works.

Comment: this is a connection issue check your firewalls

Comment: already checked multiple times. I don't have to do anything with firewalls, just restarting docker works.